# remove footnotes from DataFrame

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I'm working with the 4. table (it contains the states, capitals, surface area, inhabitants and inhabitants per km) of this url: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschland
My task is to
"Give this DataFrame its own name. The  inserted footnotes should be removed. This can be done using regular expressions as well as adjusting the corresponding pd.read_html() arguments."

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschland'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, thousands='.')
table = dfs[3].iloc[:-1,:]
table
```

the name of the table ist 'table', but i don't know how to remove the footnotes.
unfortunately I didn't even have an idea how to start.

Comment: You can do it two ways. Once you have loaded the data into a dataframe, you can remove the rows like this `df.drop(df.tail(n).index, inplace = True)` where n is the number of rows to remove. Or you can give `df = df.iloc[:-n]` or you can give `df1 = df[:-n]`

Comment: I don't want to remove multiple rows. I just want to specific remove footnotes of some cells.
The table has 5 columns with 16 rows. In the fourth column, each cell contains a footnote behind the number of inhabitants of each state, which should be remove.